# Dual cone of $K = \{(x,t) \mid \| \boldsymbol{x} \|_1 \le t \}$

Tags: convex-analysis, duality-theorems, dual-cone

This [slide](http://select.cs.cmu.edu/class/10725-S10/recitations/r10/ConvexProgramDuality.pdf) shows the dual cone of $K = \{(x,t) \mid \| \boldsymbol{x} \|_1 \le t \}$ is $K^{*} = \{(x,t) \mid  \| \boldsymbol{x} \|_{\infty} \le t\}$. Is it right? How is it proved?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $(y,t)$ is such that $\|y\|_\infty \leq t$. Select any $(x,t') \in K$.  We apply Hölder's inequality to find
$$
\langle(x,t'),(y,t)\rangle =\\ 
\langle x,y \rangle + t't \geq\\
- \|x\|_1 \|y\|_{\infty} + t't  \geq\\
-\|x\|_1 \|y\|_{\infty} + \|x\|_1 \|y\|_{\infty} = 0
$$

Now, suppose that $(y,t)$ is such that $\langle(x,t'),(y,t)\rangle \geq 0$ for all $(x,t') \in K$.

Select $(x,t') = (\pm e_i,1)$, where $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector in $\Bbb R^n$.  By the above, we have
$$
\langle(x,t'),(y,t)\rangle =
\langle(\pm e_i,1),(y,t)\rangle 
= \pm y_i + t
\geq 0 \implies\\
t \geq \mp y_i
$$
Thus, we conclude $|y_i| \leq t$ for all $i$, so that $\|y\|_\infty \leq t$, as desired.

The conclusion follows.